# Distribute QT app in linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, distribute

I want Distribute QT app in **linux** instead of Source Code.

and I want my application working in linux not installed QT.

I find Google and etc...
they says

```
1. ldd ./application and check the .so file 
2. copy .so file to another dir
3. move application file to same dir
4. then distribute(?)
```

I tried many solutions(static compile, dynamic compile) 
, but it does not working.....

How can I distribute my application....? 
(I use QT Creator in Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: So you not care about `LGPL` licence, and can statistically link with `Qt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[look at the linux-deployment-docs of qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html)

You have to build Qt statically on your system. After that you are able to link the Qt libs statically. If the ldd output doesn't print Qt related libs it was successfull and the app will run on another distribution without installation of Qt. glibc and some other shared objects 
stay shared.

So if you get not found messages(i.e.libicui18n.so.51) in the ldd output on the different system, you have to install the required elements.

Tip: 
I fixed these issues sometimes by copying the .so files from my system to the different system and called ldconfig.